# Different error messages on Boot (nouveau, hdaudio)

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I've been trying to fix this for about 4 hours now and I'm not 100% sure how to phrase the problem, so bear with me.

**Background**

I've been using my Laptop with Linux for a couple of months now and everything mostly went fine. It was running Mint, but I'm not going to ask you for help with a Mint system. Anyway, for some reason I decided that I had to reboot my System today and that's where the woes began. There were a lot of different errors, most of which I don't really recall, nor found a solution to. I still had access to my files so I decided to back them up and reinstall the OS, the latest Ubuntu this time. The initial installation went mostly fine, however here are some of the problems I've encountered:

**Problems**

After the initial installation and the first reboot (which went without a problem), the reboot after that however did not succeed.

- Nouveau prevented me from both booting the system and getting into the GRUB menu.

I don't have the exact error message, but I believe there are enough threads around on this very problem.

I "solved" this by reinstalling it again and installing the official Nvidia Driver. As per standard, through the driver I selected the integrated GPU as standard, as the Nvidia one burns through my battery life quite quickly. Yadayadayada, next reboot:

- Same problem as before, despite having the nvidia driver installed.

This time I thought it was smart. I booted up ubuntu through my flashdrive, mounted the other installation and looked up how to edit the grub.cfg without breaking anything. I replaced "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" on all the launch options, and rebooted again:

- Completely new problem: "hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec"

This wasn't just a warning, the entire system refused to boot after displaying the message. I still couldn't get into the GRUB. I also found nothing on the message except for some threads on other distributions and completely different situations.

**Status Quo**

I reinstalled ubuntu again and made sure not to leave the Nvidia GPU option. It does reboot fine, however, I would very much like this problem solved and I have no idea how. I'm hesitant to put any data on the system when it could basically break on any reboot. Is my laptop cursed or is there any way to save it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue on an ASUS ROG laptop when booting to a new install of Ubuntu 19.10.

I had to boot into Ubuntu recovery mode from the boot options screen and edit the grub file with the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

then edit the following lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.alpha_support=1“
```

And then save by hitting Ctrl+O, then exit nano with Ctrl+X, then simply run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When that finishes:

```
sudo reboot
```

**EDIT:**
After running updates and rebooting it gave me the audio error again. I went back into the grub file and removed the previous edits, ran update-grub again, then added the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf`:

```
options i915 modeset=1
```

Did a `sudo reboot` again and now everything is working! I don’t understand what the root issue was or why this works but it did for me. Hopefully, this helps someone else.